# Calling an extension method on a member variable of type T of class<T>

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

Given extension method below:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static void Serialize(this Guid guid_, StringWriter sw_)
    {
        sw_.Write(guid_.ToString("B"));
    }
}
```

and the class:

```
public class Field<T>
{
    public T value;

    public void Serialize(StringWriter sw_)
    {
        value.Serialize(sw_);
    }
}
```

I would like to do the following, but can't quite figure it out:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Field<Guid> uid;

    public Foo()
    {
        // assume StringWriter object sw;
        uid.Serialize(sw);
    }
}
```

Obviously real-life situation is more complicated, this is just a bare-bones example.

**EDIT**

Compiler errors:

error CS1928: 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Serialize' and the best extension method overload 'Ext.Serialize(System.Guid, StringWriter)' has some invalid arguments

error CS1929: Instance argument: cannot convert from 'T' to 'System.Guid'

Comment: Can T be _any_ type? What are you trying to achieve? You can't call serialize on any type `T`, because `Serialize` is only defined for the type `Guid`. What would happen if `T` were a string?

Comment: T will only be of type that have extension methods defined for. Some additional meta-data must be serialized together with value. Want to wrap it in a nice syntax

Comment: The problem here is that you are using `guid_.ToString("B")` at `Serialize`. You can use `Guid` as a generic constraint, so you need to abstract youself, but you can't, since `ToString` overload is defined at `Guid`. Can you pass string into `Serialize` extension method and call `guid_.ToString("B")` at `Foo` level?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov I could, but don't want to :) Field has more meta-data it needs to work with, hence encapsulated in it.

Comment: It's possible, but with some reflection magic. Look to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible because `T` is not certainly known at compile time whether it is `Guid` or not.

But you can do something like this

```
public class GuidField : Field<Guid>
{
    public override void Serialize(StringWriter sw_)//Assume we have made base class method virtual
    {
        value.Serialize(sw_);
    }
}
```

This works, since c# compiler knows `value` is `Guid` at compile time.

---

Following way will work but it will defeat the point of "Generics". Not recommended also.
To show how to do I give an example

```
public void Serialize(StringWriter sw_)
{
    if (typeof (T) == typeof (Guid))
    {
        ((Guid)(object)value).Serialize(sw_);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would make me create a derived class for every type I want to support. Technically a variation on the extension method approach, hmm...

Comment: @YuriyGettya Point of generics is to work on all types not like "Do it like this when it is Guid" If you do so then you defeat the purpose of generics. and btw my example also defeats it. but there is no way around. Only thing I can think of is  cast, I'll update my asnwer.

Comment: I do understand the point of generics. That's why I wanted to create levels of indirection to deal with fields on a simple way

Comment: hehe, wanted to avoid that (update) as well. Since it seems that adapter is the only viable way, so be it. dcastro's solution is the same in essence, I prefer less verbose code though.

Comment: @YuriyGettya Then short answer : **No**

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to apply a restriction such that "`T` will only be of type that have extension methods defined for".

If you really need to use generics for this, you'll have to create an adapter for each type that can be serialized, as such:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static void Serialize(this Guid guid_, StringWriter sw_)
    {
        sw_.Write(guid_.ToString("B"));
    }
}

public class Field<T> where T: ISerializableField
{
    public T value;

    public void Serialize(StringWriter sw_)
    {
        value.Serialize(sw_);
    }
}

public interface ISerializableField
{
    void Serialize(StringWriter sw);
}

public class SerializableGuid : ISerializableField
{
    private readonly Guid _guid;
    public SerializableGuid(Guid guid)
    {
        _guid = guid;
    }
    public void Serialize(StringWriter sw)
    {
        _guid.Serialize(sw);
    }
}
```

This adapter wraps an instance of a given type and exposes a way to serialize it.
Notice that `T` in `Field<T>` now only works with instances of the adapter `ISerializableField` - Now `Field<T>` knows for sure that all instances of `T` *can* be serialized.

On that note, you wouldn't need the extension method anymore, the adapter could perform the serialization itself. Unless other parts of your code will also want to serialize a guid.

**Edit**

If avoiding creating a class for each type that can be serialized is your top priority, and you don't mind losing type safety, you can use dynamic invokation:

```
public class Field
{
    private dynamic Value { get; set; }

    public void Serialize(StringWriter sw)
    {
        try
        {
            Value.Serialize(sw);
        }
        catch (RuntimeBinderException ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Instance of type {0} does not implement a Serialize method", Value.GetType()), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

No need for generics anymore. Generics enforce type safety and we're throwing that away.

Comment: Enforcing of restrictions on T is a second priority. I wanted to avoid creating a class for every type I need to support

Comment: Is that your top priority? Would you mind sacrificing type safety for that?

Comment: It looks like adapter is the only way to go here

Comment: I don't want to throw away *all* type safety .. second priority is still a priority

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are going to write a bunch of extension(Serializers) methods for every type. It's possible, but with some reflection magic.

```
public static class Ext
    {
        public static void Serialize(this Guid guid_, StringWriter sw_)
        {
            sw_.Write(guid_.ToString("B"));
        }

        public static void Serialize(this int id, StringWriter sw_)
        {
            sw_.Write(id.ToString());
        }


    }

public class Field<T>
{
    public T value;
    private static Lazy<Action<T, StringWriter>> _serializer = new Lazy<Action<T, StringWriter>>(() => (Action<T, StringWriter>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<T, StringWriter>), typeof(Ext), "Serialize"), true);


    public void Serialize(StringWriter sw_)
    {
        _serializer.Value(value, sw_);
    }

}
```

Comment: I thought about reflection, but decided against it due to performance concerns. Hmm, can we cache the results after the first reflected call resolved everything?

Comment: Updated, http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates.aspx create delegate almost as fast as direct call. And I cache it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem in your Field class is, T is a generic type and it, at this point, is "unknown" thus the extension method will not be shown as the extension method is of a concrete type for GUID. 
you would maybe need to check to see if T is of guid and if so, do the cast to GUID which will then allow you to call the extension method - so not sure that it would even compile.

as for your last example in class Foo - is uid a GUID? if so did you import the project and namespace where your Ext class exists? if not - you should then it will show up.

Comment: My answer remains the same :)