# missing extension method on constrained generic function

Tags: c#, .net, generics

My problem code is this:

```
public void MyMethod<U, T>(U Array) where U : List<T>
{
  var sum = Array.Sum();
}
```

and the compile time error I get is this:

> Error CS1929  'U' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best
>   extension method overload 'Queryable.Sum(IQueryable)' requires a
>   receiver of type 'IQueryable'

This is .NET Framework 4.6 in Visual Studio 2015. This is similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972751/calling-an-extension-method-on-a-member-variable-of-type-t-of-classt), but I'm not sure if the same answer is valid, given that the compiler can see the method is explicitly constrained.

Can anybody please give me some pointers as to why I get this error?

EDIT:

The example code can be simplified further:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(List<T> myList)
{
  var sum = myList.Sum();
}
```

Comment: Please don't name things `Array`. There already is a type called `Array` and this is just asking for confusion. First, you should name parameters using `camelCase`, not `PascalCase`; it should be `array`. Second, it is not an array, it's a list. Third, even if it were known to be an array or a list, name it according to what it *means*, not what it *is typed as*; `items` would be better than `array` or `list`. And finally, that is a bizarre constraint; it is a poor programming practice to extend `List<T>`, so what types could `U` possibly be?

Comment: Why type `U` instead of just making it a `List<T>` and dropping the constraint?

Comment: Because U is a derivative of List<T>.

Comment: So? It still works the same way.

Comment: a) saves me having to cast it later to access U specific functionality b) the problem remains the same.

Comment: What would you cast it to inside `MyMethod`? It can only be a `List<T>` anyway unless you have some hacky `if array is X then Y` type logic.

Comment: There's a new() constraint missing at the end of the method which I didn't think was relevant to the problem. Thanks to this discussion, I now realize that I could have simplified the example further.

Comment: You may want to investigate whether Jon Skeet's [`MiscUtil.Operator<T>`](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/) is of use, either to simplify your code or to gain a better understanding of how to solve your problem.  As an example, it includes a function with the signature, `public static T Add<T>(T value1, T value2)`, making it pretty easy to implement `Sum` via `Aggregate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overloads of `Sum` that have no parameters are the non-generic overloads of `Sum` where the `IEnumerable` is known to be one of the numeric types, for example:

```
public static int Sum(IEnumerable<int> source);
public static double Sum(IEnumerable<double> source);
//etc.
```

The generic overloads that allow the source sequence to be of any type require a selector that projects the items out to a numeric value.

Comment: Rather annoyingly T in my example is a numeric type, but I can't constrain it is such. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @ShunyataKharg No, it's *not* necessarily a numeric type.  It's entirely possible for the method to be called with a non-numeric type.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said that it is rather annoying that I can't constrain it as a numeric type.

Comment: What does this mean? "require a selector that projects the items out to a numeric value."?

Answer (score 1):

To add to Servy's excellent answer, you could pass in a selector to the method to use in the `Sum`, something like this:

```
public void MyMethod<T, U>(U items, Func<T, int> selector) where U : List<T>
{
    var sum = items.Sum(selector);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
MyMethod<int, List<int>>(l, i => i);
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed, using one of generic overloads is the answer to Servy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer by Servy says *that* it must be a numeric type, but not why, lets examine that.

Given the following function template:

```
public T SomeMethod<T>(List<T> items) where T : int { }
```

This is an easy one, the generic is constrained to a specific type, therefore does not need to be generic (replace `T` with `int` and it behaves the same).

Now lets assume that the type system for numeric types had a common base class called "NumericType":

```
public T SomeMethod<T>(List<T> items) where T : NumericType { }
```

That looks exactly like what you probably want, however here is the problem, *what is the return type*? Suppose the list contains `double`, `int`, `byte`, etc, each have widening conversions when multiplied, added, divided, etc by certain other types so its very difficult for the compiler to tell what the return type should be.

The same would be the problem if we were allowed to do something like:

```
public T SomeMethod<T>(List<T> items) where T : in(int, double, float) { }
```

An `int` * `int` == `int`, but `int` * `double` == `double`, or worse, `double` / `int` == `int`, as you can see, `T` just can't be inferred, which would break other constructs in the language, like:

```
var mySum = SomeMethod(myNumericList);
```

Since `var` is implicitly typed at *compile time*, it can't determine the appropriate type and therefore can't compile that statement.

The best thing you can do is to overload your function, so your prototypes become:

```
public int SomeMethod(IEnumerable<int> items) { }
public double SomeMethod(IEnumerable<double> items) { }
public float SomeMethod(IEnumerable<float> items) { }
```

Or, on the other side, you could stick with your generic constraint and do something like this:

```
public void MyMethod<U, T>(U items) where U : List<T>
{
    if (typeof(T) is int) { ((List<int>)items).Sum() }
    if (typeof(T) is double) { ((List<double>)items).Sum() }
    //Repeat for the remaining numeric types.
}
```

Or, as DavidG's answer points out, use a selector function.